# Ethernet Connection

Tags: ethernet

My college Ethernet connection requires a username and password to access the internet. Is there a way to enter the username and password without using a GUI and lunching a web browser to log in?

Maybe I could write a program to specifically log in for me and launch it on startup?

Answer (score 1):

please, don't connect your Pi directly to the internet, use router for that purpose.

this way you may put all the necessary authentication in the router settings and share the same internet connection between several devices (PC, phone, tablet, Pi) at the same time.

Comment: This isn't really an answer though. More of a comment...?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer (not putting the Pi directly on the network) is probably good advice.  But to answer the question, depending on how exactly the authorization is setup at your uni, you *may* be able to use the in-line authentication that exists in "wget" to do what you want.  There are also a number of "screen-scraping and remembering" tools that allow you to automate tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

use text-based web browser like 'lynx' and 'w3m'.